# Correct Error Trapping in R

Tags: r

This question may not belong here but I need some advice on what is considered "best practice."  I have several functions, all of which are dependent on the same inputs lets say `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Is it good practice to create an error trap function for these? or should it be coded into each function?

For example:

```
firstFunction <- function(a, b, c) {
  # check a; check b; check c; 
  # do something
}

secondFunction < function(a, b, c, from_first) {
  # check a; check b; check c; 
  # do something
}
```

Could be as follows:

```
checkthem <- function(a, b, c) {
  # check 
  # stop
}

secondFunction(a, b, c, from_first) { 
   checkthem(a,b,c) 
   # do something
}
```

Is this good practice in software development or should I avoid this?

Comment: Yes, good practice. Among other good things, it will make your code easy to maintain since you will only have to modify it in one place if needed. So write a function that checks `a`, `b`, and `c` and have both the first and the second functions call that function before they do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a new entry function where you do checks and yo call either first or second function. Since the 2 functions share many arguments , its should have behavior similarities , so it is logical to group them in the same main function. Note also that with this solution you do the call the check once in your code so it is easier to maintain.

```
firstFunction <- function(a, b, c) {
  # do something
}

secondFunction <- function(a, b, c, from_first) {
  # do something
}

mainFunction(a,b,c,type="first",...){
  do.check(a,b,c)  ##  you should define this function
  switch(type,
         first  = firstFunction(a,b,c),
         second = secondFunction(a,b,c,...))
}
```

Or as suggested in the comment:

```
run_with_check <- function(fun, a, b, c, ...){ 
      do.check(a, b, c)
      do.call(fun,list(a, b, c, ...))
}
```

Comment: Instead of `type`, you could pass a function as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I want to make sure that the package that I am writing represents best practice.  I am not a programmer, so my goal is build a "solid base" from which developers can launch better extensions.